# Rake aborted, cannot load file ./bundler/setup, ruby require errors in RubyOnRails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been working on a Ruby on Rails project for class and have run into some problems.  When I run bundle install, all of my gems install appropriately.  When I run rake db:setup, I get the following error.

```
tuggernuts2@tn-Extensa5620:~/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager$ rake db:setup
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- ./bundler/setup
/home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am also get this error when I try to run any of my unit tests:

```
tuggernuts2@tn-Extensa5620:~/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager$ ruby test/unit/user_test.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from test/unit/user_test.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    from test/unit/user_test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I'm working on this project with a group of 4 others, and no one else is getting these errors so I infer that the problem is with my setup and not with the code.

I'm running ruby version "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]"

I'm running ruby gems version 1.8.23

I'm running rails version 3.2.5

but when I run rails -v I get the same require error, and the same ./bundler/setup error as above.  I've been googling these problems for awhile and non of the solutions I've found so far have helped.

I've tried re-installing gems, I've tried running gem update -system, but that just gives me:

```
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get, using Debian official repositories.
If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.
```

The rake errors are new as of yesterday, the ruby require errors have been there pretty much since the beginning.  Life has been a struggle.

I've tried a bunch of combinations of require, require "./...", require_relative, and nothing seems to fix the require errors.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Output from: bundle exec rake db:setup --trace

```
tuggernuts2@tn-Extensa5620:~/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager$ bundle exec rake db:setup --trace
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- ./bundler/setup
/home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/config/boot.rb:7:in `require'
/home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/config/boot.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/config/application.rb:1:in `require'
/home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/tuggernuts2/Workspace/Class/baseball-manager/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec ...` at the command line before the commands you typed.

Comment: Yes I have.  Same results.

Comment: try installing rbenv and using that to manage your ruby and gems. probably have better results.